# Keep the height of 2 divs same even after their content inside them is filtered

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have 2 divs which are being displayed side by side. Each of the div contains some nested divs with some content. I want to keep the height of both the divs equal even after the content inside one of them is removed. Which means that the divs should be properly aligned.

How can I achieve that ? Here is JSFiddle so far:-

[a link] https://jsfiddle.net/k6fjavrr/1/

```
<div class="fContainer">      
  <div class="final-container">
    <div class="textIc" id="partition-5">
      <p>Introduction</p>
      <p style="font-weight:bolder;color:black;">Appréciation</p>
      <p style="font-weight:bolder;color:black;">Primary</p>
    </div>

    <div class="textIc" id="partition-5" >
      <p>Chapter 1</p>
      <p style="font-weight:bolder;color:black;">Appréciation</p>
      <p style="font-weight:bolder;color:black;">Secondary</p>
    </div>

    <div class="textIc" id="partition-5" style="">
      <p>Chapter 2</p>
      <p style="font-weight:bolder;color:black;">Appréciation</p>
      <p style="font-weight:bolder;color:black;">Tertiary</p>
    </div>    
  </div> 

  <div class="final-container-2">
    <div class="textIc" id="partition-5" style="">
      <p>Chapter 3</p>
      <p style="font-weight:bolder;color:black;">Creation</p>
      <p style="font-weight:bolder;color:black;">Tertiary</p>
    </div>  

    <div class="textIc" id="partition-5" style="">
      <p>Chapter 3</p>
      <p style="font-weight:bolder;color:black;">Creation</p>
      <p style="font-weight:bolder;color:black;">Secondary</p>
    </div>  

    <div class="textIc" id="partition-5" style="">
      <p>Chapter 3</p>
      <p style="font-weight:bolder;color:black;">Creation</p>
      <p style="font-weight:bolder;color:black;">Primary</p>
    </div>  

    <div class="textIc" id="partition-5" style="">
      <p>Chapter 3</p>
      <p style="font-weight:bolder;color:black;">Creation</p>
      <p style="font-weight:bolder;color:black;">Primary/Secondary</p>
    </div>     
</div>
```

Comment: There are a number of solutions for equalising div heights. Just search for them on SO.

Comment: I was able to make the height equal of both the divs. My issue is that the content is not aligning properly. The div height is equal but the content is not equally fit on both the divs

Comment: Then you need to explain **more clearly** what it is you are trying to achieve.

Comment: ...also, **you can't** use the same ID more than once on a page.

Comment: I can't change the ID. The html is generated using acf pro. The height of both the columns is same but the content inside is not adjusting according to the height. Check the updated fiddle

Comment: What do you mean the content inside is not adjusting to the height... what is it supposed to do and what is it currently doing?

Comment: I mean to say that there should not be any or a very little blank space inside any of those divs even if you add or remove content from them. I have attached the jsfiddle in the question.

Comment: Your cells of the table are already giving you as little space as possible. The reason the second column is larger than the first, is because the last entry of primary/secondary being longer than all the others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try if this can solve your problem, just use as many `.row` as you need

Tested on Chrome 60 and Firefox 55

```css
.cont {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 200px;
}
.column {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
}
.row {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden; /* fix FF columns */
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="cont">
    <div class="column">
        <div class="row"><h3>sdyguyfsud</h3></div>
        <div class="row"><h3>sdyguyfsud</h3></div>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <div class="row"><h3>sdyguyfsud</h3></div>
        <div class="row"><h3>sdyguyfsud</h3></div>
        <div class="row"><h3>sdyguyfsud</h3></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**[Fiddle DEMO 1](https://jsfiddle.net/ysn8tcee/)** (More nested content similar to yours)

**[Fiddle DEMO 2](https://jsfiddle.net/yo78xwq5/)** (Overflow auto, max-width and max-height for scrolling content)

In the latter example you can play around switching between "dynamic" or "fixed" grid size by just removing max-width/max-height

Comment: This is what I am getting when I add more content https://jsfiddle.net/g7oget8a/1/

Comment: @Kapoor_D Please have a look to the updated answer :)